# Converting nested array to flat hash

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
[["hello", 1], ["world", 1]]
```

I want this:

```
{ "hello" => 1, "world" => 1 }
```

I've coded something that WORKS, but feels stupid. Here it is:

```
hash = {}
array.each do |element|
  hash[element[0]] = element[1]
end 
hash
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. do as below using [`Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ] → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

```
Hash[[["hello", 1], ["world", 1]]] # =>  => {"hello"=>1, "world"=>1}
```

If you are in Ruby2.1 use [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
[["hello", 1], ["world", 1]].to_h
```